# Azure vm does not require to patch against meltdown and spectrum?

Tags: azure, security, virtual-machine

I'm confused about why Microsoft says into his official blog about the meltdown and spectre vulnerability that the customer does not need to patch the customer VM images in Azure.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/securing-azure-customers-from-cpu-vulnerability/

> This Azure infrastructure update addresses the disclosed vulnerability at the hypervisor level and does not require an update to your Windows or Linux VM images. However, as always, you should continue to apply security best practices for your VM images.

Other cloud vendors recommended such as GCP and AWS recommende their customers to patch their systems as well.

https://aws.amazon.com/security/security-bulletins/AWS-2018-013/

> While all customer instances are protected, we recommend that customers patch their instance operating systems.

https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7622138

> Read our Security Bulletins page for more information on OS provider patch status, patched image versions, and instructions for patching/updating your guest environments.

I'd like to understand what could be the reasoning behind this

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry by the way I was supposed to open it in serverfault :-(

Answer (score 1):

@snebel29 The Azure infrastructure update addresses the disclosed vulnerability at the **hypervisor level and does not require an update to your Windows or Linux VM images.** However, as always, you should continue to apply security best practices for your VM images.

More information can be found on the official blog here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/securing-azure-customers-from-cpu-vulnerability/

A hypervisor or virtual machine monitor (VMM) is computer software, firmware or hardware that creates and runs virtual machines

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: So we also have to patch our guest virtual machine kernels as everybody else is doing everywhere... therefore this was only a bad translation/understanding from my side with this sentence "and does not require an update to your Windows or Linux VM images" ???

Comment: Or this is just that the fact of patching the hypervisor automatically protects the guest virtual machine as well? even if this is running a non patched kernel? sorry but I still don't get it

Comment: @snebel29  
I meant patching the hypervisor automatically protects the guest virtual machine, I'm talking specifically about Azure.Besides that, you have to ensure you are running updates as usual on your machines.

Comment: @4c74356b41 Patching the hypervisor automatically protects the guest OS machine, hence directing my response to the VMM. The VM images themselves wouldn't need it. I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Hi @AdamSmith-MSFT thanks for confirmation, I did understood correctly then... looking deeper to other providers, seems that also they recommend to patch the guest but talks on them being protected, I guess this is related to the type of virtualization

Comment: I'd love to understand a bit more why under the hood a guest kernel not patched can't impact the guest itself... My initial questions was directed on that direction, thanks!